# How to change authentication mode (from Windows to Azure AD)

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, azure-active-directory

I have an existing WebForms application that currently uses Windows Authentication that I want to authenticate through Azure AD. The app is already configured in Azure (I have the AppID and TenantID), but the application still authenticates via Windows Authentication.

Changes were made to the application by following [this guide](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/24/protecting-an-asp-net-webforms-app-with-openid-connect-and-azure-ad/).

Most guides use MVC as their example, and I couldn't find a thorough walk through for existing WebForms applications.

Do I need to change something in the `web.config`?

I have the following codes in the Startup and Startup.Auth (which I created manually and looks exactly as what's described in the guide)

Startup.Auth

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) 
{
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "the app id";
            Authority = "the tenant id";
        });
}
```

Startup

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
  ConfigureAuth(app);
}
```

Below is the `authentication` setting in the `web.config` which I tried setting from `Windows` to `None`, but the app just threw a 401 page and didn't try to authenticate to AAD.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: Please share your startup.cs files.

Comment: @S.Walker Code snippet added. Thank you.

Comment: Show web.config.

Comment: Which part? The only recently added settings in there are the `Microsoft.IdentityModel` assemblies. `Authentication mode` is set to `Windows`

Comment: I believe that is your issue. Share the `authentication` tag of the web.config.

Comment: See updates above.

Comment: It's been so long I would have to create new project to test. Try removing the Authentication tag all together and see if it works.

Comment: Didn't work. It's just so sad that there's virtually 0 guides for WebForms.

Answer (score 2):

While I am not 100 percent sure what your issue is, Here is a working example for AAD Authentication with Web Forms.

Web.config

```
<configuration>

<!-- Azure AD Settings -->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="{ClientId}" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="{Tenant}" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="{TenantId}" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44306/" />
  </appSettings>

  <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>

    <!-- Request Login -->
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>


    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>

    <!-- Remove Forms Authentication Module. -->
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>


    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Startup.Auth.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }

            }
            );

        // This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing that last line. Lastly, after authenticating via AzureAD, the authentication mode for Windows still got triggered. Should I remove that too with `<remove name="authentication" />`?

Comment: You can. It's almost like windows authentication is being triggered at a higher level. Like, maybe it's configured at the root of the site where you are using a sub application or something.

Comment: I've fixed that windows auth issue. Now I can't get to my site after logging in via ESO; I'm getting an infinite loop. In Chrome it's endlessy switching between "waiting for login.microsoftonline.com" to "waiting for myapplication url"

Comment: @Nathan Have you got this fixed?. I have the same problem of infinite loot

Comment: after authentication,Redirecturi is giving access denied because of  <deny users="?" />. But why ? cookie is not set?

Comment: I have had this same issue numerous times on apps with Azure AD and it always seems to be a different problem. Check that the Azure AD App Registration redirect URI matches your apps URL exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share this link from MS devblogs which perfectly explains everything.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/convert-asp-net-webforms-with-windows-authentication-to-use-aad/