# How to protect all contents(.aspx,.asp,.js and img ,etc) of an asp.net web site if we use Azure AD authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

```
 <authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
<authentication mode="None">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

This configuration doesn't even taking me login screen.

[image]

My startup.cs has configuration for Azure AD. but where exactly/what code to be made for protecting all contents(.aspx,.asp,.js and .img)

```
 app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = authority,
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret= clientsecret,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = $"openid",
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    NameClaimType = "preferred_username",
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = tenant
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            }
        ); 

 private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        var policy = notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("Policy");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy) && !policy.Equals(DefaultPolicy))
        {
            notification.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId;
            notification.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
            notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(DefaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
    {
        try
        {                
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClient = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication(new ClaimsPrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity));

            // Upon successful sign in, get & cache a token using MSAL
            AuthenticationResult result = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(Scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();

            string username = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), true, "");
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            notification.Response.Cookies.Append(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                ReasonPhrase = $"Unable to get authorization code {ex.Message}."
            });
        }
    }

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

This config lets me to go login page. but even after Azure authentication , it doesn't that realize user is authenticated and not landing to default.aspx , instead it goes back login screen again. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611677/how-to-change-authentication-mode-from-windows-to-azure-ad

Comment: you're still telling the app to use Forms authentication. If you want to use AAD, then clearly you don't need your built-in login functionality anymore.

Comment: @ADyson when i remove off this config, i am able to access all contents all contents aspx,asp,js and img.,etc of my asp-net web-form app which i don't wanna happen

Comment: Well that suggests you haven't implemented the AAD auth correctly yet then. It isn't a reason to keep a dual login system.

Comment: @ADyson updated the question with Azure AD configuration. could you help on what/where exaclty we have to make code changes to protect the web contents

Comment: Sorry I'm not an expert of the specifics of that, but I can't believe there aren't tutorials etc which explain what to do already. mjwills already posted something potentially useful-looking. I only commented because of the obvious issue with trying to use two authentication systems simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

For ASPX and ASP pages you can implement an [Http Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ihttpmodule?view=netframework-4.8) that inspects the request and validates the appropiate token has been attached to the request. For other resources you might try implementing an [Http Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ihttphandler?view=netframework-4.8) that does the same.

Comment: Hi @alfredo, any pointer on sample code for this would be helpful

Comment: @user2082630 [HttpContext.User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.user?view=netframework-4.8) property. Verify if he [is in the roles required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iprincipal.isinrole?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Principal_IPrincipal_IsInRole_System_String_) or [is authenticated.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iidentity.isauthenticated?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Principal_IIdentity_IsAuthenticated).

Comment: @user2082630 Also, take a look to [ASP.NET HTTP modules and HTTP handlers.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/http-modules-handlers)