# Exception AADSTS50011 is thrown when using azure ad authentication

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory

I have been developing a C# MVC application. Using azure ad to authenticate the users.

But when deployed on IIS, it can only works when accessing the website by "https://localhost". But an error is thrown when accessing the website by "https://machinename".

AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '4e392b7a-####-####-####-####'.

2 urls are configured on the azure ad authentication:
https://machinename/
https://localhost/

The configuration in the file web.config:

```
<add key="ClientId" value="4e392b7a-####-####-####-############" />
<add key="Tenant" value="72f988bf-####-####-####-############" />
<add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
<add key="RedirectUri" value="https://machinename/" />
<add key="PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://machinename/KeepAlive/SignOut" />
```

Comment: I wrote an answer on this a while back. You need to check that EVERYWHERE the reply URL is specified it matches exactly. Does the registered app in azure match the app config settings? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611677/how-to-change-authentication-mode-from-windows-to-azure-ad/49615560#49615560

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, you must ensure that the reply URL in the Azure portal is exactly the same as the reply URL configured by the application.

I have answered [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776175/aadsts50011-the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-does-not-match-the-reply-url/63792388#63792388) before, There is a general solution to the problem of **not match**:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request URL, you will find redirect_uri, copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

---

**Update:**

Thanks for the solution provided by @Tom. For this error, you also need to add the port :

```
https://machinename/{port}
https://localhost/{port}
```

Comment: I have found the solution. The port is also needed to add in the authentication page. In my case, it is <https://machinename:4435/, https://localhost:4435/.
Thank you all the same.

Comment: @Tom  Thanks for the solution, I will add it to the answer to end the thread.